# Как получить ссылку на загруженный файл в дропбокс?

Tags: dropbox, api, php

Загружаю по АПИ-дропбокса файл.

Как мне получить публичную (или приватную) ссылку для дальнейшего открытия?

Может, кто сталкивался?

Если просто читаю файл, то получаю след.:

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
print '<pre>';
# Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
require_once MODX_BASE_PATH . "dropbox/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";
use \Dropbox as dbx;

$accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$f = fopen(MODX_BASE_PATH . "robots2.txt", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/rob.txt", $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($fileMetadata);
```

Ответ:

```
    Array
(
    [rev] => 10208031c0d71
    [thumb_exists] => 
    [path] => /rob.txt
    [is_dir] => 
    [client_mtime] => Wed, 03 Dec 2014 20:37:35 +0000
    [icon] => page_white_text
    [bytes] => 25
    [modified] => Wed, 03 Dec 2014 20:37:35 +0000
    [size] => 25 bytes
    [root] => dropbox
    [mime_type] => text/plain
    [revision] => 66056
)
```

В ответе подсказали, что нужно расшарить  этот файл.
Но как вызвать эту функцию?

echo $dbxClient->createShareableLink($result['path']); и все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не работал с Api dropbox, но интуиция подсказывает что его нужно с начало [расшарить](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/source-class-Dropbox.Client.html#1007-1038).